# Remove http/https for ACF URL field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I was trying the snippet below. I'm trying to remove "http" and "https" for the URL field in order to make the output look nicer, but I can't really get it working. I can't tell what is going wrong here.

```php
<?php if ( $site = get_field( 'vendor_website' ) ) : ?>
    <?php
    $site = str_replace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $site);
    $site = rtrim($site, '/');
    echo '<a class="vendor-link" href="' $site '">' $site 'target="_blank">' '</a>';
    ?>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you’re trying to just show the host of the URL, you may give parse_url a try:

```
$host = parse_url( $site, PHP_URL_HOST );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

**Edit as per comments**

Let me expand the example, imagine `get_field( 'vendor_website' )` returns something like https://example.org/test, and you want to just show "example.org", while leaving the link to the original URL. The code should be something like this:

```
<?php if ( $site = get_field( 'vendor_website' ) ) : ?>
    <?php $host = parse_url( $site, PHP_URL_HOST ); ?>
    <a class="vendor-link" href="<?php echo $site ?>" target="_blank">
        <?php echo $host ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So I have tried something like this. How it return the root url then the ACF filed url. How can I remove the root url from here? Thanks
`code`
<?php if ( $site = get_field( 'vendor_website' ) ) : 

$host = parse_url( $site, PHP_URL_HOST );

echo "<a href='$host'>$host</a>";

endif; ?>

Comment: See the updated answer with the new example, hope it helps.